# How do I use yield inside a callback on redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, zendesk

I have a callback which I need to return true or false to trigger some external action, I need to make an API call inside this callback, so I need to get the state and dispatch some actions inside the callback, I don't know if I can use eventChannel because this callback could not be a generator, only a plain function. I need to do something like this.

```
  zafClient.on('ticket.save', () => {
      const state = yield select();
      yield put(actionWithApiCall())

      // I need to wait for the action to finish and then return something 
      // based on the response from the API
      // I know how to block the saga to wait for the action dispatched 
      // the problem is that I can't use yield here

      return somethingfromthestore;
  });
```

Btw, this is zendesk API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not going to be able to pass a generator function to that API. The work around is to dispatch an action directly to the redux store and then write a saga that listens for that action.

```
zafClient.on('ticket.save', () => reduxStore.dispatch(actionWithApiCall()))
```

You will have to make the redux store exportable from where you create it. So that you can directly access it here.

Comment: But then how do I wait until the response from the API is inside the store so I can return something based on the updated store?

Comment: Use `yield take(MY_API_ACTION)` and then `yield select()` to get the data from the store in a new Saga

Answer (score 0):

One of the challenges is how to `yield` in the callback.  How about importing `dispatch`? Isn't dispatch the non-generator version of `yield`?

Should you be using React, doing so seems to be an option.

In the same saga that you use to specify the callback, you can subsequently listen for the action created in the dispatch/action creator callback.  That's done by specifying another `watchFor` function (in my setup, any number of exported `watchFor` functions get added to the pool of saga watchers).

The paired saga `worker` can finalize whatever needs to happen to the data returned from the API call before using your final action creator to "document" the workflow by updating the store.

The other option might be to wrap the api call in an `eventChannel` (see: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1178).

- E